# BLOB Oracle PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, oracle

Требуется хранить файл в базе Oracle Database посредством BLOB, используя язык PHP. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать? Конкретно запись в базу и извлечение из нее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загрузка BLOB в базу (в данном примере используется UPDATE, но с таким же успехом можно использовать и INSERT). Также требуется записать имя файла.

```
$conn = oci_connect('login', 'password', 'server', 'utf8');
$lob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, "update document set file_blob = empty_blob(), blob_name = '$file_name' where id = :id returning file_blob into :blobbind");

  oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':id', $id_doc);
  oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':blobbind', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
  oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT); 

  if ($lob->savefile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) { //индекс tmp_name обязателен!
    oci_commit($conn);
    echo "BLOB uploaded";
  }
  else {
    echo "Couldn't upload BLOB\n";
  }
  $lob->free();

oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);
```

Выгрузка из базы

```
$conn = oci_connect('login', 'password', 'server', 'utf8');
$query = 'SELECT FILE_BLOB, BLOB_NAME FROM DOCUMENT WHERE ID = :MYBLOBID';
$stmt = oci_parse ($conn, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':MYBLOBID', $id_doc);
oci_execute($stmt);
$arr = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC);
$result = $arr['FILE_BLOB']->load();

header("Content-type: text/plain");
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename='.$arr['BLOB_NAME']); 
echo $result;

oci_close($conn);
```

Пример представлен для текстовых форматов файлов (включая .doc)

Answer (score 0):

Официальная документация от Oracle может служить примером http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18555/ch_twelve_blobs.htm#TDPPH183